# Enable Submit after password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, form-submit

In Profile Section of the user the password field is not mandatory however I set a function which calls the password validation.

Password and Confirm Password Field

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" onfocus="submission()">
<input type="password" id="cpassword" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control" onfocus="submission()">
```

Submission JS Function

```
function submission() {
    $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);

    $('input[type="password"]').keyup(function() {
        if(passwordValidation()) {
            $(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
}
```

Password Validation Function

```
function passwordValidation() {
        $('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
            var pswd = $(this).val();
            if (pswd != '') {
                var x = document.getElementById("password").value;
                var y = document.getElementById("cpassword").value;

                if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
                    $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                } else {
                    $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                }

                //validate letter
                if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
                    $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                } else {
                    $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                }

                //validate capital letter
                if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
                    $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                } else {
                    $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                }

                //validate number
                if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
                    $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                } else {
                    $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                }

                //validate symbol
                if ( pswd.match(/[!@#$%^&*]/) ) {
                    $('#symbol').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                } else {
                    $('#symbol').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                }

                //validate symbol
                if ( x == y && x != "" && y != "" ) {
                    $('#confirm').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
                } else {
                    $('#confirm').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false
            }

        }).focus(function() {
            $('#pswd_info').show();
        }).focusout(function() {
            $('#pswd_info').hide();
        });

        //return true;
    }
```

The return of `passwordValidation()` is allows undefined not getting any false or true result. I tried multiple ways but no luck of success, anyone can help telling me what's wrong with the code.

[image: Password Passed all checks]

[image: If password didn't pass all checks]

The process of the password check is as following.

User should pass all conditions to turn on green then the submit button will be enabled otherwise if one or multiple conditions are not matched the submit button will be disabled. And if the inputs are empty it will be disabled as well. I don't want to allow the submission before setting the right password and confirming it.

Comment: simply add `disable` attribute in your submit button HTML

Comment: The `return` inside the  password keyup only return to that event callback , not to the outer `passwordValidation` function which has no return

Comment: @ZainKhan this is not the process I'm looking for.

Comment: @charlietfl can you elaborate with a clear solution or advice, thanks

Comment: @David Bulk then please describe the process as well.

Comment: The process is explained